# Why this upgrade question was flagged as off-topic? Can we ask similar questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm referring to this question: [What improvements can I make in my laptop (Asus X555LJ)?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10028/what-improvements-can-i-make-in-my-laptop-asus-x555lj)

I don't see a reason why it was closed. It is asking "What upgrades do I make to my Asus X555LJ laptop to run Xamarin in Visual Studio smoothly?", which to me seem related to this site, yet it was closed as off-topic (Technical support).

Now I'm quite confused since I want to ask a similar questions like "What can I upgrade in this laptop to?" and "How can I upgrade this laptop display to FullHD IPS? What panel can I choose and would I need any other cables or hardware?"

I am afraid they would be closed as off-topic in here, yet they also would be off-topic, or left without answer in Superuser, as they would be **too specific** and asking for **hardware reccomendation**.

Does it mean I would have to seek answers on third party websites, even though this question might have belonged to this site? In my opinion it creates a very negative user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at our [Help Center](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for a full definition of what questions can be asked here. Quoting from that:

> Hardware Recommendations is a community-run website to help you find a specific product for your needs. That means you can ask for **a recommendation for hardware to perform a specific task**.
>
> **We cannot help with technical issues with existing hardware.**

Since your question is asking for technical support, it's not on-topic for this site, which is why it was closed. You might be able to find help on Super User, which is more focused towards existing hardware - but remember to read [their topic guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) before you post as well.

Comment: How do I make a good "hardware upgrade" question, then? I want to upgrade my laptop to increase it's performance and looking for recommendations for electronic hardware I can put in it , why would it be a technical support question?

Comment: @Jzuken The absolute crux of it is "be specific" - the more specific, the better. Your question actually has two aspects to it - there's the "will it make a significant difference?", which is tech support and off-topic - and there's "what other upgrades would you advise", which is _closer_ to being on-topic but needs to be specific. I'd suggest figure out what components you want to upgrade, work out what they need to be/do/be compatible with/cost, etc, and then ask a question per component.

Comment: It is not my question, but I was confused as to why it was closed. Just to be sure, is it ok to have a question that says "Can I upgrade X? If so, what are my options? What alternative options do I have, like using WLAN PCI lane for eGPU?"

Comment: @Jzuken "Can I" is a question you need to answer; we can't do that here. "What are my options" is okay, as is specifying that you're open to alternatives.